# android setActive(false) issue with opengles

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have an application that displays png pictures with opengles (2D) but it sometimes crashes leaving no errors in the log.

The only thing I get is a warning message "Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 6259 uid 10080" (random numbers)

I display pictures by running through a vector of pictures, if I add objects statically, it works but I need to add them randomly, by using "vector.add(new Pict())" and it crashes around the glDrawElements function

I tried debugging with dev tools, it works fine in debugging mode but not in real time, is there any other way for debugging? (gl debugging flags crashes too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that dynamic memory allocation is more expensive that keeping useless objects in memory, well, switching into static allocation, 1 object/mesh and recycle killed meshes works fine, even on emulator. 
Moral : gc is useful when it's useless =D